# Group checkboxes in JSFiddle : Part 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I am trying to do group checkboxes by selecting selectAll. Please check JSFiddle for code sample

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ItsMeSri/L6zau/1/)

```
  <fieldset>
    <!-- these will be affected by check all -->
    <div><input type="checkbox" ID="checkall1" onclick="CheckAllClick('checkall1');"> Check all</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <!-- these won't be affected by check all; different field set -->
    <div><input type="checkbox" ID="checkall2" onclick="CheckAllClick('checkall2');"> Check all</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</div>
</fieldset>


   function CheckAllClick(id){
    alert(id);
     $(id).closest('fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);

}
```

[Part 2: Continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548627/group-checkboxes-in-jsfiddle-part2)

Comment: If you have solved this, please either delete the question or post your own solution as an answer if you think it'll help others.

Comment: @Bergi there other series question related to same. I know I allowed to ask one question for one post. Thatsway I opend part2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some issues in your function: Try this way:

#### Js

```
   function CheckAllClick(elem) {
       $(elem).closest('fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', elem.checked);
   }
```

#### Markup

```
 <input type="checkbox" ID="checkall1" onclick="CheckAllClick(this);">Check all</div>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M7kBP/)**

Pass the element in the onclick function as `this` and access it in your code.

If you can go with jquery approach then:

Add a class to your checkall check boxes

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" ID="checkall1" >Check all
```

With the same code, if you want to make the label click to check the checkbox then just wrap them in `label` tag, same thing you can do with all the checkboxes by wrapping them in label which generally is a standard way:

```
 <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" ID="checkall1" >Check all<label>
```

Bind an event handler to a class

```
$('.checkAll').on('change', function(){
    $(this).closest('fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
})
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XtC39/)**

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is this.

```
$('[id^=checkall]').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('fieldset').find(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', function(i,oldval){
       return !oldval; 
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qe9GY/)

Comment: This !oldVal will not work if you check one then select global one. http://jsfiddle.net/ItsMeSri/Qe9GY/3/

Comment: @James123 use `return true;` instead, then.

Comment: How to do if one of the items unchecked then global (checkall) also unchecked?

Answer (score 0):

```
function CheckAllClick(id){
    alert(id);
    $(id).closest('fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', 'checked');
}
```

The simplest solution is just to changed the checked property to checked seeing as you only selecting inputs you want already

And pass this into your onclick

```
<div><input type="checkbox" ID="checkall2" onclick="CheckAllClick(this);"> Check all</div>
```