# Group checkboxes in JSFiddle: Part2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

[Group checkboxes in JSFiddle : Part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538488/group-checkboxes-in-jsfiddle-part-1)

After solving  Part 1 for Global Checkbox for All Check/Uncheck. I have couple other issues to solve.

1. If I unchecked any of the items from list. Automatically  Global (Check all) should be unchecked.

[image]

2. If I checked all of items individually. Automatically Global (Check all) should be checked. like this.
   [image]

### Code

```
 <fieldset>
    <!-- these will be affected by check all -->
    <div><input type="checkbox" ID="checkall1"> Check all</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <!-- these won't be affected by check all; different field set -->
    <div><input type="checkbox" ID="checkall2"> Check all</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</div>
</fieldset>
```

JS

```
   $('[id^=checkall]').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('fieldset').find('input').not(this).prop('checked',this.checked);
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ItsMeSri/Qe9GY/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register a callback which will check whether all the checkboxes in the current group is checked or not

```
$('input[id^=checkall]').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('fieldset').find('input').not(this).prop('checked',this.checked);
});

$(':checkbox').not('[id^=checkall]').click(function(){
    var all = $(this).closest('fieldset').find('[id^=checkall]');
    var chks = $(this).closest('fieldset').find('input').not(all);

    all.prop('checked', chks.length == chks.filter(':checked').length);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5fCEU/)